# Why is memory leaking in this code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm a newbie in C and I have memory leak in my program.

```
static int MT_reduce(MT_table** MT)
{
    MT_table* newMT = new_MT((*MT)->argc);

    /// fill data in the newMT ////

    if(isReduced == 1 && newMT->size > 0)    
    {
        MT_free(*MT);
        *MT = newMT;
    }

    return isReduced;
}
```

In other place I call this procedure:

```
    while(MT_reduce(&MT)==1);
```

I'm freeing old resources before assigning to `MT` the address of `newMT`, but why do I get a memory leak? How I can replace `MT` with `newMT` without leaking memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid memory leak you should edit the code in the following manner:

```
static int MT_reduce(MT_table** MT)
{
    MT_table* newMT = new_MT((*MT)->argc);

    /// fill data in the newMT ////

    if(isReduced == 1 && newMT->size > 0)    
    {
        MT_free(*MT);
        *MT = newMT;
    } else {
        MT_free(newMT);
    }

    return isReduced;
}
```

You should always free newMT even when you do not copy it.